# How to pass argument in Laravel 5, using html tag?

Tags: laravel-5

Hi, am new to laravel5, In the HTML code, I need to call this below destroy function. I'd written this in Controller page.

Could anyone help me?

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Book::find($id)->delete();
    return Redirect::route('books.index')->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return $input (withInput) but it is not available because you did not create it.

It seems that you want to return a record that is already deleted? If you want to return the deleted data you can do this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // First get the data
    $data = Book::find($id);
    // Then delete it
    Book::find($id)->delete();
    // Finally return it
    return Redirect::route('books.index')->withData();
}
```

Or you can try it in one line (not sure this works):

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $data = Book::find($id)->delete();
    return Redirect::route('books.index')->withData();
}
```